# Why is the fundamental matrix of a linear system of ODEs always invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Why does $\phi^{-1}(0)$ exist, where $\phi(t)$ is the fundamental matrix of the system $\dot{x}=A(t)x$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$? I am not able to figure this out.

Comment: I'm not sure, but isn't a fundamental matrix invertible by definition?

Comment: Unless $A(t)x$ fails the uniqueness and existence theorem, it may not be invertible, to my knowledge.

Comment: There may be some slight differences in definitions, but e.g. if you take Wikipedia's definition http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_matrix_%28linear_differential_equation%29 the columns of a fundamental matrix must be linearly independent solutions of the system.  A square matrix whose columns are linearly independent is invertible.

Comment: @Robert Israel Wish I could upvote again as your last sentence is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the ODE $\dot x = - A(T-t) x$.  Its fundamental solution $\psi(t)$ satisfies $\psi(T) \phi(T) = \phi(T) \psi(T) = \text{Identity}$.  (In other words, I am solving the equation $\dot x = A(t) x$ backwards in time.)